# Broken link on Privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

The link to the 'approve edit suggestions' page on [the privileges page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges) is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the link for now, we will add it back in when the feature is made public.